# Facebook Developer Tabs Heroku and Other

Tags: php, git, heroku, hyperlink

i was wondering if you could help me.
I am Currently Running Windows 8. Vs2012 with .php plugin. I have followed all the steps on the developer app page of facebook and then heroku using the git command line interface. and i seem to keep getting all kinds of errors. Does anybody know of an up to date decent tutorial of how to create, edit and upload a facebook application?

Comment: If you want to hepl you must insert the error here.

Answer (score 1):

you can see the video on this link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=HgiONvm5JB0

it will teach you how to pull and edit a facebook application

the video may get outdated so here is another link

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#create-an-app

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged (links tend to get stale over time).
Please consider editing your answer and adding a synopsis here.

Comment: @kleopatra the link I have provided is provided and managed by facebook and heroku itself so the link will not get stale.